# Using findOne in mongodb to get element with max id

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to retrieve one element from a mongo collection, the one with the greatest _id field. I know this can be done by querying:

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(1)
```

But it kind of seems unelegant and I was wondering whether there is a way to get that specific element using findOne()

Note: I want to do this because, from what I've read in [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), the first bytes correspond to the miliseconds since the Epoch and thus, the last element being inserted will have the greatest _id. Is there any other way to retrieve the last element inserted in a collection?

Comment: There's nothing inelegant about your original method, actually.

Comment: Reminder that the `ObjectId` is usually created by the client driver, so it's only as accurate/reliable as the clients being used. If two drivers insert at the same second, the results won't be predictable.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You should use `find`, like you already are, and not aggregation which will be slower since it needs to scan *all* the values of _id fields to figure out the max.

As comments pointed out there is *no* difference between using find() and findOne() - functionally or elegance-wise.  In fact, `findOne` in the shell (and in the drivers which implement it) is defined in terms of find (with limit -1 and with pretty print in the shell).

If you *really* want to do the equivalent of

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).pretty()
```

as `findOne` you can do it with this syntax:

```
db.collection.findOne({$query:{},$orderby:{_id:-1}})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I expected there'd be some kind of better implementation for my query than calling find just to get that 1 result, but if findOne is simply an elegant find I guess there really is no difference.

Comment: correct.  and aggregation (which you accepted as correct answer) is actually a very much wrong answer because it *would* scan all the _id values, where find uses _id index to only scan a single value.

Comment: The `$orderby` operator is [deprecated since version 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/orderby/) . Use `cursor.sort()` instead.

Comment: @Avishay there is absolutely no reason that I can think of that what you say would be true.  If you don't find a match findOne and find limit 1 are absolutely identical, just like if you do find a match.

Comment: @Avishay the blog post you linked to is quite wrong - it was constructing find() but not actually checking if anything was matched.   There are comments that explain why it's wrong.

Comment: YMMV, but I've typically seen better performance by projecting only the field you care about in the original find, like so: `db.collection.find({}, {_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).limit(1).pretty()`

Answer (score 13):

You can get max _id using aggregation of mongodb. Find and sort may overkill's.

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: '',
        last: {
            $max: "$_id"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how is this more elegant than find()?  It's never going to be faster and in most instances could be a lot slower.

Comment: in fact, it's not find and sort - find with sort uses an index to immediately select a single value.  Your aggregation answer would have to scan the entire range of values).

Comment: this worked well in an aggregation pipeline that was already doing a $group

Answer (score 1):

**with PHP driver (mongodb)**
using `findOne()`

```
$filter=[];
$options = ['sort' => ['_id' => -1]]; // -1 is for DESC
$result = $collection->findOne(filter, $options);
$maxAge = $result['age']
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pymongo

tonystark = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

mydb = tonystark["tonystark_db"]
savings = mydb["customers"]

x = savings.find().sort("_id")
for s in x:
    print(s)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for your answer! Can you offer an explanation as to how this works and why this is a strong solution to the problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
$maxId="";

$Cursor =$collection->find();

foreach($cursor as $document) { 
    $maxid =max($arr=(array($document['id'])));
}

print_r($maxid+1);
```