# how to get the max value of a field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

like:

```
{id:4563214321,updateTime:long("124354354")}
```

there are always new collections enter the db, so I would like to **always** get **latest** updated documents aka the largest update time. how to design the shell script? thanks in advance.

Comment: you might get ans here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118210/using-findone-in-mongodb-to-get-element-with-max-id

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a combination of limit and sort to achieve this goal.

`db.collectionName.find({}).sort({"updateTime" : -1}).limit(1)`

This will sort all of your fields based on update time and then only return the one largest value.

I would recommend adding an index to this field to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks! I have already tried the method and this really works, And I got further about this: For instance I got 100 documents initialized and another 100 came in. SO, the database would re-sort all of the 200 documents again so would another data enter, which means that every time when there is update in the database, it would run all of the data to sort. I am wondering now if there is more effective way to do this? And is there any possibility to operate on the server side to make this happen?

Comment: @OscarShaw Index the field you are sorting on, it will improve performance dramatically. see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/ optimization of this is another question so I ca't go into too much detail here. it's against SO policy.

Comment: Great! I think index is gonna help! One last question and I am not even know if it is possible to do so. I got multiple fields in one document. HOW could I return the entire document(all of the fields inside)based on the largest updatetime. I mean not just group together and use $max to return a new named field. I would like to return the very documents where the largest updateTime is in. Should I write some javascript method to do it?

Comment: @OscarShaw the command i gave you would return the entire document based on highest value of "uptime". type the command in a mongo shell, use dummy data if you need to but the entire document will be returned. if this helped you please mark as correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a repeated question, you can find an answer in this link
[Using findOne in mongodb to get element with max id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118210/using-findone-in-mongodb-to-get-element-with-max-id)

use like this,

`db.collection.find().sort({updateTime:-1}).limit(1).pretty()`

as findOne you can do it with this syntax:

`db.collection.findOne({$query:{},$orderby:{_updateTime:-1}})`

Comment: I have another question is that I got multiple fields in one document. HOW could I return the entire document(all of the fields inside)based on the largest updatetime?