# meteor get the maximum member registration number

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am building a meteor app for a new members' club. Members will be allocated a registration number as they register. This will be an incremental number running from lets say 1.  On the registration form i have a field for member number.I want this field to be auto populated with the last registration number + 1.

I have a people collection with the _id field storing the member number as follows _id:memberNo.

How can i fetch the maximum member number, add 1 to it and populate the member number field?

Comment: Be careful with 2 members registering at the same time.

Comment: Do members need to see their reg number while they are registering? It seems odd to populate the form on the client - why not do it on the server so it's secure and you don't have to worry about multiple registrations as per the comment above?

Comment: Also, if you're using an incremental number starting at 1, then you don't need to find the maximum ID number - you just need to know how many members there are in the collection and add 1: `newMemberId = Members.find({}).count() + 1`

Comment: @rubie To be sincere, I have been unable to pull out this one. I want to go with your suggestion because of concurrent registration and also to hide this member number during registration but I can't crack it on Meteor.

Comment: After almost giving up on this, tweaked your uggestion a little bit and came up with this Template.regForm.helpers({
 membersCount: function() {
    return Members.find().count() + 1
  }
});
 Then inside the template used {{membersCount}}. This works but as you mentioned I dont think it is a good thing to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a mongo query. Something like this should help:

```
db.collection.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(1)
```

Template.templateName.helpers({
    var currentMax = db.collection.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(1)

More information available in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118210/using-findone-in-mongodb-to-get-element-with-max-id)

Comment: Thanks @blueren for your answer.