# How can I retrieve document with max value in one of its fields Mongo Db

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Can anyone tell me how How can I retrieve document with max value in one of its fields Mongo Db.Using mongoTemplate Class

here is an Example

```
{
    "_id" : "post 1",
    "author" : "Bob",
    "content" : "...",
    "page_views" : 5
}
{
    "_id" : "post 2",
    "author" : "Bob",
    "content" : "...",
    "page_views" : 9
}
{
    "_id" : "post 3",
    "author" : "Bob",
    "content" : "...",
    "page_views" : 8
}
```

so i want following result

```
{
    "_id" : "post 2",
    "author" : "Bob",
    "content" : "...",
    "page_views" : 9
}
```

The record with max page_views

Comment: Not a duplicate, because although not specified in the title, the user specifically asks about MongoTemplate which is spring-data-mongodb and not covered by the dupe link.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933904/using-spring-data-mongodb-is-it-possible-to-get-the-max-value-of-a-field-withou instead

Answer (score 5):

This would be your mongoDB query, I hope you can implement it in your driver

```
db.<collection name>.find({}).sort({'page_views':-1}).limit(1);
```

You will get an array of length one containing the requested document. `-1` indicates sorting in descending order. `limit(1)` limits the number of documents to 1. So you will get the document containing the highest number of `page_views`.